# Is the use of "alternative options" redundant in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, redundancy

Is use of the word "alternative" in the following sentence redundant?

> After examining the different types of beer on the menue, Joe took several minutes to consider his **alternative** options before ordering...

Comment: Using "alternative" there suggests "options as opposed to his beer options" .. there are beer options, then there are other options.  If he were just selecting a type of beer, yes it would be redundant and also confusing.

Comment: I think the intended sense would usually be inferred, but also a clumsiness detected. '[T]o consider his options' itself sounds rather heavy-duty here. How about '... Joe took several minutes making his mind up' or 'Joe took several minutes before deciding what he would order'?

Answer (score 1):

[Tom22](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/213359/tom22) says in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389027/is-the-use-of-alternative-options-redundant-in-this-sentence#comment917496_389027):

> Using "alternative" there suggests "options as opposed to his beer options" .. there are beer options, then there are other options. If he were just selecting a type of beer, yes it would be redundant and also confusing.

Comment: I wouldn't say it "suggests" that. I'd say that's one way of interpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I would choose either "alternatives" or "options", but not both. A more frequently used word in casual language might be "choices".

To say "alternative options" tends to imply that someone has made a tentative choice but is considering additional choices.